# Laravel & MongoDB: Cannot drop an existing collection using migrate:fresh

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-migrations, jenssegers-mongodb

I am unable to drop MongoDB collections by running migrate:fresh. The project is on Laravel 5.7 and we are using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`. When I try to run migrate:fresh, an error comes up saying

> MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException  : a collection 'project.drivers' already exists

If I manually delete the collections and run migrate:fresh, the collections are created again. This is confusing as if the collection can be created using `Schema::connection('mongodb')->create('drivers', ...`

I am unsure why the collection is not dropped when running `Schema::connection('mongodb')->drop('drivers');`

Below is one of my migration files that throws the error.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateDriversTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('mongodb')->create('drivers', function (Blueprint $collection) {
            $collection->string('first_name');
            $collection->string('last_name');
            $collection->string('id_number');
            $collection->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('mongodb')->drop('drivers');
    }
}
```

mySQL is the main database connection. And my .env file looks like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project

DB_CONNECTION_MONGO=mongodb
DB_HOST_MONGO=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_MONGO=27017
DB_DATABASE_MONGO=project
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any extra information or code samples. I have tried to use what the documentation states, but the same error is thrown. I am new to using MongoDB with Laravel, and have searched the internet and found no solutions that work.

**UPDATE**

I just moved the `Schema::connection('mongodb')->drop('drivers');` function directly above `Schema::connection('mongodb')->create('drivers', ...` database in up() and the collection drops. So it seems the down() function is getting ignored.

**UPDATE 08/11/2018**

I have tried to use the `dropIfExists('drivers')` function but the collection still does not drop.

Comment: I have the same issue on lumen 8. Rollback with steps=2 does not work. but rollback without steps it works. Reason is that \Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::compileOrdersToArray receives  array:2 [
  "batch" => -1
  "migration" => -1
] and its code treats that arrat as array of arrays. This is happening with mongodb (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and not with mysql.

Comment: I submitted an issue: this https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/2304